# In mongo aggregate pipeline, how to distinguish null and 0 when using a sum operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo 3.0.4 to group data by a key. Suppose we have some mongo documents like

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'name': 'leo'}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'name': 'leo'}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'name': 'amy'}
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'name': 'amy'}
```

I try to aggregate by the key "name" and sum all the a,b,c fields using the code below

```
[
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$name',
        'a': {
            '$sum': '$a'
        },
        'b': {
            '$sum': '$b'
        },
        'c': {
            '$sum': '$c'
        }
    }
}
]
```

and get the result like that

```
[
{
    '_id': 'leo',
    'a': 2,
    'b': 4,
    'c': 0
},
{
    '_id': 'amy',
    'a': 4,
    'b': 4,
    'c': 0
}
]
```

The question is the "c" field in group leo is also 0, which I expect to be null. 
and the expected result should be

```
[
{
    '_id': 'leo',
    'a': 2,
    'b': 4,
    'c': null
},
{
    '_id': 'amy',
    'a': 4,
    'b': 4,
    'c': 0
}
]
```

or

```
[
{
    '_id': 'leo',
    'a': 2,
    'b': 4
},
{
    '_id': 'amy',
    'a': 4,
    'b': 4,
    'c': 0
}
]
```

I know the `$sum` operator treats none numeric fields as 0, so is there any ways to do that? How can I distinguish null and 0 in aggregate when using a sum operator?

Comment: I guess you cannot achieve this in single queries. you have to split your query in two.

Comment: Is there any chance to be achieved in one pipeline? like using match, project...

Answer (score 1):

i tried this,may be this will help for you

```
    db.gg.aggregate([{
            '$group': {
                '_id': '$name',
                'a': {
                    '$sum': '$a'
                },
                'b': {
                    '$sum': '$b'
                },
                'c': {
                    '$sum': '$c'
                },
                cdata: {
                    $push: {
                        c: "$c"
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                a: 1,
                b: 1,
                c: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: [{
                            $setIsSubset: [
                                [{}], "$cdata"
                            ]
                        }, true]
                    }, null, "$c"]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

output:

```
     { "_id" : "amy", "a" : 4, "b" : 4, "c" : 0 }
     { "_id" : "leo", "a" : 2, "b" : 4, "c" : null }
```

Comment: thanks for help, $push is useful in this case, the only problem is that the documents may be very large, and I am afraid that use $push may affect the  performance. anyway its a good idea, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

finally I found this

```
[
{
    '$project': {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 1,
        'c': 1,
        'c_count': {
            '$cond': [
                {'$gt': ['$c', null]},
                1,
                0
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$name',
        'a': {
            '$sum': '$a'
        },
        'b': {
            '$sum': '$b',
        },
        'c': {
            '$sum': '$c'
        },
        'c_count': {
            '$sum': '$c_count'
        }
    }
},
{
    '$project': {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 1,
        'c': {
            '$cond': [
                '$c_count',
                '$c',
                null
            ]
        }
    }
}
]
```

the first project can figure out the doc count that contains the field c,
since the null field in [bson-sort-order](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/bson-types/) is low. After that, it is possible to digtinguish null and 0 in the following pipeline